# How to delete entire column if no entries made

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me with my simple code?

```
Sub DeleteBlankColumn()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Notice how the code will delete *everything* if nothing is inserted in column H? Problem, the chart has a header in H5, "Staff". Because "Staff" is written in a cell, it won't delete the column.
How can I change the code to only look at cells H6 and down (where the entries are made)? That way, if all cells from H6 down are blank, it deletes the entire column, including its header.

Thank you so much!

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone! This is what I was able to find:

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
If lr < 6 Then Columns("H").Delete
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
If Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
    'Delete
End If
```

Comment: Sorry! This didn't work for me :( I've updated my question if it helps. @Taosique thank you!

Comment: @BMRobin Did you try substituting "H6"  for the Range index and xlDown instead of xlUp in Taosique's suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Cindy Thank you. I tried the your suggestion but it didn't work :( This is what I have:
Sub DeleteStaffColumn()

If Range("H6" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row = 1 Then
    'Delete
End If
    
End Sub

Comment: No, leave out & Rows.Count. Since you want to START from H6 and work down (instead of starting at the end of the rows and going up - apparently based on your original question, which you've since changed) you have to code accordingly... THINK about what the code is supposed to do and does :-)